# EL1008E: Property or field 'applicationName' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public or not valid?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Been stuck with this error for a while now.

> EL1008E: Property or field 'applicationName' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public or not valid?

I'm trying to get the records from database through thymeleaf, but always gets this error. I think I've declared everything that is needed this.

Here's my code

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sms_alert", schema = "public")
public class SmsAlert {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sms_id")
    private Long smsId;
    
    @Column(name = "application_name")
    private String applicationName;

    @Column(name = "sms_flag")
    private String smsFlag;

    public SmsAlert() {
        
    }
    
    public SmsAlert(String applicationName, String smsFlag) {
        super();
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
        this.smsFlag = smsFlag;
    }

    public Long getSmsId() {
        return smsId;
    }

    public void setSmsId(Long smsId) {
        this.smsId = smsId;
    }

    public String getApplicationName() {
        return applicationName;
    }

    public void setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
    }

    public String getSmsFlag() {
        return smsFlag;
    }

    public void setSmsFlag(String smsFlag) {
        this.smsFlag = smsFlag;
    }
    
}
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/smsAlert/{applicationName}")
    public String viewApplicationSmsAlert(@PathVariable("applicationName") String applicationName, Model model) {
        System.out.println(applicationName);
        model.addAttribute("sms", smsService.findSmsFlagByAppName(applicationName));
        return "test";
    }
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface SmsRepository extends JpaRepository<SmsAlert, Long> {
        
    @Query(value = "SELECT s.application_name, s.sms_flag  FROM public.sms_alert s WHERE s.application_name= :applicationName ", nativeQuery = true)
    public String findSmsFlagByAppName(@Param("applicationName") String applicationName);
```

Service

```
@Service
public class SmsService {
    @Autowired
    private SmsRepository smsRepository;
    
    public List<SmsAlert> findAll() {
        return smsRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    public String findSmsFlagByAppName(String applicationName) {
        return smsRepository.findSmsFlagByAppName(applicationName);
    }

    public void updateSmsFlag(String applicationName, String smsFlag) {
        smsRepository.updateSmsFlag(applicationName, smsFlag);
    }
    
}
```

HTML File

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="invTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table-primary">
                        <th id="terminalId">Terminal ID</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="sms : ${sms}">
                        <td th:text="${sms.applicationName}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findSmsFlagByAppName` method in `SmsRepository` returns a `String`.  Your controller is putting that `String` in the model with the variable name `sms`.  Then in your view you are referencing `${sms.applicationName}` which is trying to evaluate the `applicationName` property on that `String`, which of course does not exist.

You could make the error go away a number of ways.  One is, populate the model withe `applicationName` as a `String` and then in the view simply refer to that `String`.

Another option is to rework the `findSmsFlagByAppName` method to return a `SmsAlert`.

Comment: The option to make the  findSmsFlagByAppName method return a SmsAlert worked. Thanks for the help